# How can I access my WAMP server from a laptop using WiFi router

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, apache-http-server, wamp

I have put my WAMP server online and edited the `httpd.conf` and set `require all granted`

My `httpd.conf` file:

```
Listen 192.168.1.12:80
Listen [::0]:80

 <Directory />
    AllowOverride none 
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
AllowOverride all
Allow from 192.168.1.12
Require all granted
```

My computer IP address is static at 192.168.1.12(server) and the laptop IP is 192.168.1.15

When I connect my laptop to the network with a cable it works but when connecting via the WiFi it doesn't work.

What else can I do?

Comment: A lot of wifi routers have the option to isolate the wireless network from the wired network.  Have you checked your router settings for "WiFi Isolation" or "Wireless Isolation"?

Comment: Details of your router would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy really.

First undo the mods you did to this

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

This say listen on any ip address and is as WAMPServer is delivered, your change was unnecessay.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none 
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

The above section should never be changed, as its is this that says nothing on the disk that Apache is installed on can be accessed by Apache. It normal practice with a web server to start by giving it absolutely no access to anything, then opening up just what it requires access to. Then should you get hacked, at least the hacker does not find it easy to access anything on your system.

This may seem a little pedantic, but the next step after accessing your server from a laptop at home, will be opening it up tp the univrse so you can show a friend or client. So best to never make the changes to this that you did.

Now in this section change it to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

First `allow from 192.168.1.12` is Apache 2.2 syntax and you are using Apache 2.4 where the syntax is as above.

Second `192.168.1.12` was your servers ip address and not your laptop's ip address. Now laptops normally us the DHCP server in the router to dynamically allocate them an ip address i.e. the laptops ip address may not always be the same.

So if you use only the first 3 of the 4 quartiles of the IPV4 address it say to Apache, anyone on this networks subnet is allowed access. So if you have a friend over with his/her laptop or buy another laptop, they can all get in